# how many elements of S

Tags: combinatorics

Let S be the set of the set of 5x5 matrices such that diagonal elements are either 0 or 1 and sum of element  of every row and column is 1. Then number of elements in S is

a) $5^2$

b)$5^5$

c) 5!

d) 55

Comment: Is this a multiple choices so does not need a complete proof or you are looking for a detailed answer?

Comment: ofcourse detailed answer!! @ B.S.

Comment: It would be necessary to specify what are the entries... Integers? real numbers?

Comment: If entries are arbitrary, the question itself is wrong (or was mistyped). See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If all the entries in the matrix are said to be 0 or 1, it is easy to see why. The first 1 in the first column can be in 5 rows. The second 1 in next column cannot be in the same row, so now you have 4 choices. The third 1 has 3, and so on. In total, one can have $5x4x3x2x1$ of those, $5!$. However, you didn't clarify this.

**Update**

If the entries are arbitrary integers (or reals), the answer is infinite and the multiple choice question is wrong.

Take an arbitrary matrix $m$ with entries in $\Bbb Z$ (or $\Bbb R$). Reverse the rows and subtract from it giving $m_2 = m-Rev_{r}(m)$; this has columns that sum to zero. Now reverse the columns $m_3 = m_2 - Rev_{c}(m_2)$. This now has columns and rows that sum to zero, and both diagonals are zero. Finally, add the identity, $I+m_3$. This matrix will contain *some* entries off the diagonals with arbitrary numbers and certainly fulfils the conditions: all rows and columns sum to 1 and has only 0/1 in diagonals. But there too many of those as our initial $m$ was arbitrary, so it can't be just $5!$.

An example arbitrary $m_3$ that I got trying an example (add $I$ and you got it),

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & -b & 0 & b & 0 \\
 -a & 0 & 0 & 0 & a \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 a & 0 & 0 & 0 & -a \\
 0 & b & 0 & -b & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: I do not understand how can you conclude if the user has not specified what are the entries...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, you were right, kind of. See updated answer :)

Comment: The evenness argument is not very convincing. For example, identity satisfies the conditions, but is its own transpose. You'd have to argue that an even number of symmetric matrices satisfy the given conditions.

Comment: @ronno, hum, you are right. The whole question is wrong anyway. I believe there is a typo from the OP.